# Data is not saved to Anonymous Parse User

Tags: java, android-studio, parse-platform

I am new to android and I am trying to develop an Uber Clone app. I am registering the user as an Anonymous User onto the Parse Server. I have two options for the User, to select either the driver option or the rider option. When the user selects one of these two options, I want to save this data(whether the user is a rider or a driver) to the Parse User object in the form of a String with key "riderORdriver".
This is how I am trying to save the string to the Parse User object -

```
String userType = "rider";
if(switchButton.isChecked())
{
    userType = "driver";
}

ParseQuery<ParseUser> parseQuery = ParseUser.getQuery();

parseQuery.whereEqualTo("username", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());

final String finalUserType = userType;
parseQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
        if(e == null && objects.size() > 0)
        {
            ParseUser user = objects.get(0);
            user.put("riderORdriver", finalUserType);
            user.saveInBackground();
        }
    }
});
```

The Current User is always an Anonymous User as I have turned off the enable automatic user and I am using ParseAnonymousUtils to log in the Anonymous User. The new Anonymous user appears in the User class in the Parse Dashboard, but the column "riderORdriver" does not appear in it. I have also tried the simpler version of this -

```
ParseUser User = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
User.put("riderORdriver", userType);
User.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {
        if(e == null)
        {
            Log.i("Status", "User Updated");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.i("Status", "User not updated");
        }
        //none of these two messages is being printed to the log
    }
});
```

But that doesn't seem to work either. Can someone please point out the reason as to why this is happening?

**Edit** I am writing this code in the OnClick function of a button. Could that be the reason for this?

Comment: The simplest version should work. Do you see any exception when executing this code? Is the request arriving to your Parse Server and is it successfully responding?

Comment: @DaviMacêdo I cannot see any exception in the Run Log. Also, in the simplest method of saving the riderORdriver string to Parse, when I added a Save CallBack, I used Log.i() to print message to the Log. One for when the ParseException in the callback is null, and another for if it isn't null. But surprisingly, nothing from the saveCallBack code is printed to the Log. I think that the saveInBackground function isn't getting called.

Comment: @DaviMacêdo I have also added the SaveCallback object so you can see the code.

Comment: @DaviMacêdo Thanks for taking out the time to take a look at this, but somehow I solved it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know what the problem was, but clicking Clean Project in the Build Section did it for me. The request is now updating with the "riderORdriver" string. I had already tried to Clean the Project once, but all in vain. This time, it worked. Maybe that's the best bet at solving this issue.